# How to suppress the words "if" and "then"?

Tags: logic, notation

My math teacher keeps making us write mathematical sentences with "regular" words. I always ask her if it is possible to supress them but she always says "no" or she starts laughing.

Take for example this definition of an injective function:

$\forall x_1, x_2 \in D_f, \text{if}\space\space x_1 \neq x_2,\text{then}\space\space f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$

$\forall x_1, x_2 \in D_f, \text{if}\space\space f(x_1) \neq f(x_2) , \text{then}\space\space x_1 \neq x_2 $

My question is about the notation: how to suppress the words "if" and "then" and use mathematical symbols instead?

Comment: I am sure a logician will chime in with a proper answer, but I have always personally used the implication arrow. For instance an injective function

$$ (\forall x_1,x_2 \in D_f) (x_1 \not = x_2 \implies f(x_1) \not = f(x_2))$$

Comment: I could answer your question but I'm not going to. You should listen to your teacher - she's doing you a big favor! Learning to write clear and correct mathematical English (or whatever other natural language) is an important and useful skill - much more important than learning formal logical symbols. (In my experience students who insist on writing things using such symbols typically get things _wrong_ as a result.)

Comment: I would go even further than your teacher.  Instead of $\forall$, write in words "for all".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for your opinion/explanation. It really helped me understanding some of my teacher's thoughts.

Comment: @GEdgar she used to write that way before but then she suddenly changed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus

Comment: If your goal is to communicate with machines (e.g. if you are programming a mathematical calculation to run on a computer), then learning to replace "if-then" by appropriate symbols is a useful skill. On the other hand, if your goal is to communicate with human beings (e.g. if you are writing a homework problem for your poor teacher to grade), then you should use words like "if-then".

Comment: Erk, "$\forall x_1, x_2 \in D_f, \text{if}\space\space x_1 \neq x_2,\text{then}\space\space f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$" this is classless. Either replace all connectives and quantifiers or replace none at all.

Comment: With all due respect and without trying to bother anyone: that "Lambda calculus" thing is one of the most terrible, cumbersome and useless things **for mathematicians** I've ever seen. I understand (I think so, at least) that it is more used in computer science and, in fact, more in formal languages, and I would have probably never met it if it weren't for a friend's brother that used it in a discrete mathematics course. Even after writing that "Unfortunately lambda calculus hasn't been well received by mathematicians.." in the text book, it is also used for mathematics students. Beats me.

Comment: If you abuse of formal notation, then it can become unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to suppress the "if... then" then I guess what you are looking for is $"\iff"$. E.g. in your case you would write:

$\forall x_1 , x_2 \in D:$ $x_1 \neq x_2 \iff f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

(EDIT: Yes, all you need to do to make the implication go both ways is to put a double headed arrow. No need to make two seperate statements with the arrow pointing opposite ways in each!)

I wouldn't particularly recommend trying to purge your writing of all words since this usually makes things harder to read for others and yourself. To an extent this is a matter of taste, though.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the whole statement. Could you update your answer so I can see the difference? It would be the arrow to become a bi-arrow?

Comment: I have made the edits you asked :) But as a comment below points out, there is no need for the $"\Leftarrow"$ part of your definition. The right to left direction is something that is true for all functions and nothing to do with injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *your* statement can be mathematically rephrased as:

> $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in D_f, \space\space $$
>   $$x_1 \neq x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$$

But keeping in mind the *true definition of **injective** functions*,

> $$\forall x_1, x_2 \in D_f, \space\space $$
>   $$x_1 \neq x_2 \iff f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$$

That is, the statements are *bi-implications*.

Comment: Not only do I disagree that the "true" definition uses a biconditional (in my experience much more common is seeing a conditional only), the direction $\impliedby$ is a consequence of the definition of a function, it doesn't even add information, it is simply true.

Comment: @GitGud I agree with you. The first one is just the mere and straightforwardf mathematical representation of the statement the OP has made and the second one is the addition of the fact that the "if.. then" the OP has mentioned should actually be "if and only if" since it is a *function*, like you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert:

- $\color\red{\text{if }a\text{ then }b}$        to $\color\green{a \implies   b}$
- $\color\red{\text{}a\text{ only if }b}$        to $\color\green{a \implies   b}$
- $\color\red{\text{}a\text{ if }b}$             to $\color\green{a \impliedby b}$
- $\color\red{\text{}a\text{ if and only if }b}$ to $\color\green{a \iff       b}$